# How can I retrieve an entity that has a member collection that has a specific value?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria-api, hibernate-criteria

So, I have this schema

```
@Entity
class A {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @MapKey("mapKey")
  Map<Integer, B> bMap;
}

@Entity
class B {
  @ManyToOne
  A a;

  int mapKey;

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "B_Cs", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_id", nullable = false))
  @Column(name = "c", nullable = false)
  Set<String> cSet;
}
```

and I want to retrieve all the As that have a Map that has a B that has a given String in the cSet.

I tried to look in the Hibernate documentation but got lost in all the things explained there, so I tried to find an example somewhere else on the net, but I had no luck.

What's a good way to retrieve my As?

Comment: Not sure if you can achieve this through annotations, I'd write some HQL on a separate method.

Comment: When you say annotations, you mean criteria?